# Excel VBA WorkSheet.Copy After Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I want to copy a worksheet and place it DIRECTLY after another sheet. But I having trouble when there are hidden sheets involved.

Using Excel 2013 I open a new workbook.
Add a Sheet after "Sheet1". Rename it "HiddenSheet2"
Add a Sheet after "HiddenSheet2". Rename new sheet "Sheet3"
So I have "Sheet1" - "HiddenSheet1" - "Sheet3"
Then hide "HiddenSheet1"

Next run this VBA Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 AS Worksheet
Set wst = Sheets("Sheet1")
wst.Copy After:=Sheets(wst.Index)
End Sub
```

The inserted sheet get placed after "HiddenSheet2" and not after "Sheet1".
I found that the copied sheet becomes the active sheet.

[Get Handle on last worksheet copied by Worksheet.Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248822/get-handle-on-last-worksheet-copied-by-worksheet-copy?rq=1)

[VBA Copy Sheet to End of Workbook (with Hidden Worksheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990465/vba-copy-sheet-to-end-of-workbook-with-hidden-worksheets)

But my problem is I need the sheet to remain in a specific order.

Thanks

Edit:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 AS Worksheet
Set wst = Sheets("Sheet1")
wst.Copy After:=Sheets(wst.Index)
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(wst.Index)
End Sub
```

This doesn't get the new sheet directly after "Sheet1" either.

Comment: Why not use `wst.copy after:=wst`?

Comment: What @glh said. You already have `wst` as a Worksheet variable. Just use that for the `After` argument :)

Comment: `wst.copy after:=wst` and `wst.copy after:=Sheets("Sheet1")` produces the same results. My new sheet get place after the hidden sheet and not directly after "Sheet1"

Comment: But yes it make more since to use `wst.copy after:=wst`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing code can be added

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 AS Worksheet
Set wst = Sheets("Sheet1")
wst.Copy After:=Sheets(wst.Index)
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(wst.Index)
```

> ```
> If (ActiveSheet.Index - wst.Index - 1) <> 0 Then
>         Sheets(wst.Index + 1).Visible = True
>         ActiveSheet.Move After:=wst
>         Sheets(wst.Index + 2).Visible = False
>     End If
> ```

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. I figured I might end up doing a semi hack. But just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy. 

I can it up a little:
`If (ActiveSheet.Index - wst.Index - 1) <> 0 Then
        Dim bVisible As Boolean
        bVisible = Sheets(wst.Index + 1).Visible
        Sheets(wst.Index + 1).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=wst
        Sheets(wst.Index + 2).Visible = bVisible
    End If`
Is probable safe to say their a hidden sheet as thats the only time this is a problem but I'll save the Visibility just in case Excel throws me for another loop.

Comment: +1 good one. Didn't know about that *issue* with hidden sheets.

Answer (score 0):

The index property is zero base, unless specified elsewhere. Sheets property is base of one. You need to either:

1. Add 1 to the index, not preferred.
2. Reference the .name property, better.
3. Reference the sheet variable you have I.e. Wst.copy after:=wst, best.
4. Or move the hidden sheet to after the new one.

Comment: Thanks I will avoid using indexes when I can although that wasn't the problem in this case.